# C#: Does ResumeLayout(true) do the same as ResumeLayout(false) + PerformLayout()?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, generated-code

I have looked at the generated designer code of `Form`s and `UserControl`s, and in the `InitializeComponent()` method they always start with

```
    this.SuspendLayout();
```

and end with

```
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();
```

But from what I can see in the msdn documentation of those methods, wouldn't ending with

```
    this.ResumeLayout(true); // Or just this.ResumeLayout()
```

do the exact same thing? Or am I missing something here?

*Asking because I will be adding a bunch of controls in a different method, and thought I should do the suspend-resume routine to be nice and efficient. But can't figure out what the reason for those two method calls are when you can seemingly just use one...*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using reflector:

```
this.ResumeLayout() is equal to this.ResumeLayout(true)
```

But

```
this.ResumeLayout(true) is not equal to this.ResumeLayout(false) + this.PerformLayout()
```

Reason:
When ResumeLayout is called with false, there is a control collection that is looped through and the LayoutEngine calls InitLayout on each of the controls in the layout.

Comment: So to get the correct behaviour, I guess I would have to call them both?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks that way

Comment: Alright. Well, thanks for the info then :) I must say that I don't quite understand the point of `ResumeLayout(true)` then, but it probably has its reason.

Comment: I'd like to request somebody volunteer a common or typical scenario where a "true" parameter will produce different behavior or results than a "false" parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**SuspendLayout**

> When adding several controls to a
>   parent control, it is recommended that
>   you call the SuspendLayout method
>   before initializing the controls to be
>   added. After adding the controls to
>   the parent control, call the
>   ResumeLayout method. This will
>   increase the performance of
>   applications with many controls.

**PerformLayout**

> It forces the control to apply layout
>   logic to all its child controls. If
>   the **SuspendLayout** method was
>   called before calling the
>   **PerformLayou**t method, the **Layout** event is suppressed. The **layout** event can be suppressed using the SuspendLayout and
>   ResumeLayout methods.

MSDN Link - [PerformLayout Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8aw0sd8.aspx)

Comment: That makes sense, but what about `ResumeLayout`? Does calling `ResumeLayout(true)` perform the same work as calling `ResumeLayout(false)` and `PerformLayout()`?

Comment: I think this link will answer your question - http://www.ddj.com/architect/184405892