# Windows forms, how can I add controls to a form post-initialization without overlapping with adjacent controls in the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Adding a control that has it's `Dock` property set to `DockStyle.Fill` outside of the form's `InitializeComponent()` function doesn't consider the adjacent controls in the form.

In this case my `DataGridView` control is being underlapped by my `MenuStrip` control.
[image: Data Grid View Overlapping with Tool strip menu]

I assume it has something to do with `SuspendLayout()` ,`ResumeLayout(false)`, and `PerformLayout()` and I've tried mimicking the function calls done in `InitializeComponent()` as so:

```cs
            mainForm = new Form1();
            //add post-init control
            mainForm.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            mainForm.SuspendLayout();
            mainForm.TableMainGridView = mainForm.GetGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(mainForm.TableMainGridView)).BeginInit();
            mainForm.Controls.Add(mainForm.TableMainGridView);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(mainForm.TableMainGridView)).EndInit();
            mainForm.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            mainForm.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
            mainForm.ResumeLayout(false);
            mainForm.PerformLayout();
```

But it doesn't change anything.

After some more [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339758/c-does-resumelayouttrue-do-the-same-as-resumelayoutfalse-performlayout) it seems that `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` are only used for the performance of forms with many controls.
`PerformLayout()` is supposed to "force the control to apply layout logic to all its child controls." but as to what this *"layout logic"* is remains a mystery to me.

Comment: It's not really clear what this code: `mainForm.TableMainGridView = mainForm.GetGridView();` is doing or what it's supposed to do. Do you have a DataGridView in this Form already? Are you adding it to the Form.Controls collection again? Or was it `null`? What is `GetGridView();` doing?  In any case, why to the Form.Controls collection directly? You should use a docked Panel container or TableLayoutPanel to host new child controls with this kind of layout (multiple docked objects, apparently) otherwise use `BringToFront()`/`SnedToBack()` to set the z-order (which is part of the *layout logic*).

Comment: @Jimi it just returns a new dgv object with all of it's formatting/settings  (I moved it out of the form class to be a static function instead).
The point is that i'm adding this one dgv control after `InitializeComponent()` which i assume happens when a new form object is created.

If there's no fix for this I'll just have to have the same code twice, once in `GetGridView()` and once in `InitializeComponent()`. If i call `GetGridView()` from `InitializeComponent()` it works but i can no longer use the [Design] window.

Comment: The Panel/Container would probably work, forgot that was a thing, but I might as well just have duplicate code if there's any disadvantage to using it, I'll test it out.

Comment: Forget about `InitializeComponent()`, this is related to how Docking and z-order/z-index work and combine. Controls with lower z-index have higher z-order. See the  quick notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469851/7444103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476266/7444103). It's still not clear what `TableMainGridView` is when the Form is created. Is it an already Docked Control or a just Field set to `null`?

Comment: it's a null field.